# url rewriting using .htaccess?

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using codeigniter. There is a url patern: `localhost/mysite/application/assets/projects/projectname`

The `projectname` part is dynamic. Now I want to rewrite that url to: `localhost/mysite/projectname`

Is it possible using `.htaccess`? If it is what will be the code.

Comment: you really should follow the CI guide when you are creating urls.

Comment: actually projectname is a folder that contains a new project that needs to automatically load when localhost/mysite/projectname is hitted. how ci guide can help ? can you be little bit more specific ?

Comment: If you follow CI, `assets` would be a `controller`, `projects` would be an `action` in that controller and `projectname` would be a `param` for that action. Being a param, you would easily fetch it and query the database for it. It's really easy when you follow the rules. It isn't when you don't.

Comment: I think you mean: localhost/mysite/controller/projects/projectname and using that projectname param I redirect to that folder. But what I really want is : A folder that contains a project doesn't depend on codeigniter,the link will be public so that anyone can browse that project by hitting url: localhost/mysite/projectname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/.-]+)$ index.php?$1 

RewriteRule ^(CSI) index.php?/CSI
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

**EDIT**

Once try this way

```
RewriteRule ^(/application/assets/projects)$ http://localhost/mysite/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: It didn't solve my case.What I want is to replace a fraction of url with a (/). That is /application/assets/projects/ to /